# JavaScript Reaction Game (Generate random drawings not showing)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Java reaction game, get random drawings not working. the color and shape doesnt show when you start the game.

This is what the game should do randomly generates up to 10 drawings of different shapes, sizes and colors. Each player gets to play 10 rounds. On each round, they are asked to click on a specific shape of a certain color. For instance, they may be asked to click on a blue square. Once they click on the correct drawing, the program records their reaction time and proceeds to the next round. After 10 rounds, the game proceeds to the next player. When all players have completed their rounds, the game displays the results of all players, ranked based on their average reaction time. The player with the shortest average reaction time wins.

[look of the game on desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqzSc.png)

**the java file**

```
// Constants
const TOTAL_ROUNDS = 10;
const SHAPES = ['square', 'circle', 'triangle'];
const COLORS = ['blue', 'red', 'green'];

// Game variables
let players = [];
let currentPlayer = 0;
let currentRound = 1;
let reactions = [];

// DOM elements
const startButton = document.getElementById('startButton');
const instructionsContainer = document.getElementById('instructionsContainer');
const drawingContainer = document.getElementById('drawingContainer');
const resultsContainer = document.getElementById('resultsContainer');

// Initialize the game
function initializeGame() {
  const playerCount = parseInt(prompt('Enter the number of players:'));
  if (isNaN(playerCount) || playerCount <= 0) {
    alert('Invalid player count. Please enter a positive number.');
    return;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < playerCount; i++) {
    const playerName = prompt('Enter player ' + (i + 1) + ' name:');
    players.push({
      name: playerName,
      reactionTimes: []
    });
  }

  startButton.addEventListener('click', startRound);
  startButton.disabled = false;
}

// Start a round
function startRound() {
  // Clear the previous round's elements
  drawingContainer.innerHTML = '';

  // Get the current drawing requirements
  const shape = getRandomElement(SHAPES);
  const color = getRandomElement(COLORS);
  const instructionsText = `Click on the specified shape and color: ${color} ${shape}`;
  instructionsContainer.textContent = instructionsText;

  // Generate random drawings
  for (let i = 0; i < TOTAL_ROUNDS; i++) {
    const drawing = generateDrawing();
    displayDrawing(drawing);
  }

  // Start the timer
  const startTime = Date.now();

  // Listen for click event on drawingContainer
  drawingContainer.addEventListener('click', function handleClick(event) {
    const clickedDrawing = event.target;
    const clickedShape = clickedDrawing.dataset.shape;
    const clickedColor = clickedDrawing.dataset.color;

    // Check if the clicked drawing matches the required shape and color
    if (clickedShape === shape && clickedColor === color) {
      const reactionTime = Date.now() - startTime;
      reactions.push(reactionTime);
      players[currentPlayer].reactionTimes.push(reactionTime);
      currentRound++;

      // Check if the current player has completed all rounds
      if (currentRound > TOTAL_ROUNDS) {
        currentPlayer++;
        currentRound = 1;
      }

      // Check if all players have completed the game
      if (currentPlayer >= players.length) {
        endGame();
      } else {
        startRound();
      }
    }
  });
}

// End the game and display results
function endGame() {
  // Disable the start button
  startButton.disabled = true;

  // Calculate average reaction times
  const playerResults = players.map((player) => {
    const reactionTimes = player.reactionTimes;
    const averageReactionTime = calculateAverage(reactionTimes);
    return {
      name: player.name,
      averageReactionTime: averageReactionTime
    };
  });

  // Sort the players based on average reaction time
  playerResults.sort((a, b) => a.averageReactionTime - b.averageReactionTime);

  // Display the results
  let resultsHTML = '<h2>Game Results</h2>';
  playerResults.forEach((result, index) => {
    const rank = index + 1;
    resultsHTML += `<p>${rank}. ${result.name}: ${result.averageReactionTime.toFixed(2)} ms</p>`;
  });
  resultsContainer.innerHTML = resultsHTML;
}

// Generate a random drawing
function generateDrawing() {
  const shape = getRandomElement(SHAPES);
  const color = getRandomElement(COLORS);
  return { shape, color };
}

// Display a drawing on the drawing container
function displayDrawing(drawing) {
  const drawingElement = document.createElement('div');
  drawingElement.classList.add('drawing');
  drawingElement.dataset.shape = drawing.shape;
  drawingElement.dataset.color = drawing.color;
  drawingContainer.appendChild(drawingElement);
}

// Get a random element from an array
function getRandomElement(array) {
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
  return array[randomIndex];
}

// Calculate the average of an array of numbers
function calculateAverage(numbers) {
  if (numbers.length === 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  const sum = numbers.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0);
  return sum / numbers.length;
}

// Initialize the game when the page loads
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', initializeGame);
```

**the html file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Reaction Game</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Reaction Game</h1>
  <div id="gameContainer">
    <div id="instructionsContainer">
      <p id="instructions">Click on the specified shape and color:</p>
    </div>
    <div id="drawingContainer"></div>
    <button id="startButton">Start Game</button>
    <div id="resultsContainer"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**the css file**

```
#gameContainer {
  text-align: center;
}

#instructions {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#drawingContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.drawing {
 
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.square {
  background-color: blue;
}

.circle {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid green;
}

button {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#resultsContainer {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Could someone please assist?